# How do I use a MySQLdb connect object on imported function

Tags: python, mysql-python

Noobish question to be sure. I have tried to move some common code into a separate module and use the code as an imported function. The code makes a MySQL query through MySQLdb. When the function is part of the main script, it runs just fine. When I import the function from a separate module, the function fails because the cursor object is no longer defined. Is there a way to import functions without defining a separate cursor object for just the imported function?

Here is an coded example. This works:

```
import MySQLdb
#from mod2 import lookup_value

def get_db_connection(database_name):
    db = MySQLdb.connect('localhost', 'user', 'pswrd', database_name)
    cur = db.cursor()
    return db, cur

def lookup_value(user_name):
    query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM x_user_%s" % (user_name)
    cur.execute("%s" % (query))
    return cur.fetchone()

db_name = 'mg_test' # database name
user_name = 'test' # name of a specific table in the database

db, cur = get_db_connection(db_name)
value = lookup_value(user_name)
```

When I move the code for lookup_value to a second file, and import it ('from mod2 import lookup_value'), the code fails because the cursor object is undefined. The imported version of lookup_value only works if I create a cursor object for its use. This seems very inefficient. What is the best way to handle this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `lookup_value` searches for the `cur` within the file you import it in. You could put this all in a class.

```
class DB():
    def __init__(self,database_name):
        db = MySQLdb.connect('localhost', 'user', 'pswrd', database_name)
        self.cur = db.cursor()


    def lookup_value(self,user_name):
        query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM x_user_%s"
        self.cur.execute(query, (user_name,))
        self.result = self.cur.fetchone()
        return self.result
```

now you can do

```
....
db = DB(db_name)
value = db.lookup_value(user_name)
```

when you import the DB `from mod2 import DB` the last part should still work.

Also take note of how i execute the query in `lookup_value` this ensures the data is sanitized

Comment: When I get done hacking the code together for my project, I look forward to actually learning python. I'm not so sure I forward I look to rewriting it, however :)  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should pass a cursor variable to your functions if you want them to be independent.
In any case you should use in a function only local variables and variables passed as parameters.